# Markdown parsing and '\n' ignorance

Tags: html, markdown

I have a markdown text editor and in my back-end I parse it to html and save in DB.

But when user puts ***new line*** into text it gets ignored. I tried `$markup = str_replace("\n", "<br />", $markup);` but this function replaced all **new lines** even in **li** so the text looks horrible.

This is how it is saved in db:

```
<ul>
<li>
<span>test</span>
</li>
<li>
<span>test</span>
</li>
</ul>
<span>before ENTER
after</span>
```

So the ***new line*** symbol is saved. But in browser it is ignored.

How can i solve this problem? Mayb

Comment: This is expected behaviour for Markdown. Content between HTML tags is treated as raw HTML and not parsed for Markdown syntax. New lines are therefore output as new lines in HTML source code (and treated like any other white space) and not converted into paragraph elements.

Comment: @Quentin so it is impossible to fix it?